# AngularJS button directive not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I'm currently trying to build a RESTful API using Angular and NodeJS. Currently I'm facing a bit of a annoying problem. After creating a button to take the user to the details page of my application, the button simply doesn't respond. The button itself is coded right I think, it's the directives I'm quite unsure about.

main app.js

```
    var myApp = angular.module('myApp', [ 'ngRoute']);

myApp.config(function($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider.when('/', {
            controller: 'BooksController',
            templateUrl: 'views/books.html'
    })
        .when('/books', {
            controller: 'BooksController',
            templateUrl: 'views/books.html'
        })
        .when('/books/details/:id ', {
                controller: 'BooksController',
                templateUrl: 'views/book_details.html'
        })
        .when('/books/add', {
                controller: 'BooksController',
                templateUrl: 'views/add_book.html'
        })
        .when('/books/edit/:id ', {
                controller: 'BooksController',
                templateUrl: 'views/edit_book.html'
        })
        .otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/'
        });
});
```

books.html (view)

```
<div class="panel panel-default" ng-init="getBooks()">
  <div class="panel-heading">
    <h3 class="panel-title">Latest Books</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="panel-body">
        <div class = "row">
            <div ng-repeat="book in books">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <h4>{{book.title}}</h4>
                    <p>{{book.description}}</p>
                    <a class =" btn btn-primary" href ="#/books/details/{{book._id}}">View Details</a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <img class ="thumbnail" src="{{book.image_url}}">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

books.js

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp');
myApp.controller('BooksController', ['$scope', '$http', '$location', '$routeParams',function($scope, $http, $location, $routeParams){
    console.log('LOADED');
    $scope.getBooks = function(){
        $http.get('/api/books ').success(function(response){
            $scope.books = response;
        });
    }
    $scope.getBook = function(){
        var id = $routeParams.id;
        $http.get('/api/books/'+id).success(function(response){
            $scope.book = response;
        });
    }
}]);
```

I think the problem might be here : `$http.get('/api/books/'+id).success(function(response)`because that's what I'm using to route from the button to the details page.

Here is my book_details.html page

```
<div class="panel panel-default" ng-init="getBook()">
  <div class="panel-heading">
    <h3 class="panel-title">{{book.title}}</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="panel-body">
        <div class = "row">
            <div class = "col-md-4">
                <img src ="{{book.image_url}}">
            </div>
            <div class = "col-md-8">
                <p>{{book.description}}</p>
                <ul class = "list-group">
                    <li class ="list-group-item">Genre: {{book.genre}}</li>
                    <li class ="list-group-item">Author: {{book.author}}</li>
                    <li class ="list-group-item">Publisher: {{book.publisher}}</li>
                    <li class ="list-group-item">Pages: {{book.pages}}</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Plus I am getting 404 on `{{book.image_url}}`, I have no idea why. Could this contribute to the button not being clickable ?

Comment: For your 404 error, use `ng-src="{{book.image_url}}"`. See https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSrc

Comment: I wouldn't use `ng-init` to load state (see the warning here ~ https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit). Instead, use a `resolve` section in your route config. I'd also use different controllers for book vs books

Comment: Are u able to directly visit  the details  URL's through the browser ? that should help u narrow it further. cos there is no issue with your button as such

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As indicated in the comments, I'd use separate controllers and avoid `ng-init` entirely.

For example

```
myApp.controller('BooksController', function($scope, $http) {
    $http.get('/api/books').then(function(response) {
        $scope.books = response.data;
    });
})
.controller('BookController', function($scope, book) {
    $scope.book = book;
})
```

and in your route config

```
.when('/books/details/:id', {
    resolve: {
        book: function($http, $route) {
            return $http.get('/api/books/' + $route.current.params.id).then(function(response) {
                return response.data;
            });
        }
    },
    controller: 'BookController',
    templateUrl: 'views/book_details.html'
})
```

Don't forget to remove the `ng-init` directives from your templates.

Answer (score -1):

[AngularJS $http](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http)

Since most part of your code looks fine, I guess what you did wrong is

`$scope.books = response;` and `$scope.book = response;`

As the document said, the response object contains

```
data – {string|Object} – The response body transformed with the transform functions.
status – {number} – HTTP status code of the response.
headers – {function([headerName])} – Header getter function.
config – {Object} – The configuration object that was used to generate the request.
statusText – {string} – HTTP status text of the response.
```

Change `$scope.books = response;` to `$scope.books = response.data;` and `$scope.book = response;` and `$scope.book = response.data;` then try again.

Comment: didn't help. It only broke my api so that I couldn't view my books.

Comment: I'm sorry, hope you can find someone do help :(

Comment: OP is using the deprecated `success` callback which takes the `response.data` as its first argument